# Cassandra Configuration Isnt Initializing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I keep getting error on trying to connect to cassandra running on localhost 9041 from spring framework. Its getting too frustrating, tried all possible options - please do help. I am running apache-cassandra-3.11.3 version.I would appreciate any help to resolve this. I want to use CassandraJPARepo model but even basic loading is not going through. Please do help.

I am trying to connect to cassandra to execute the code and in configfuration it is failing.

Its simple code. Application main class-->loading CassandraConfiguration.
Note: One specific thing i want to also highlight, instpite of having default application.properties, environment object is also not initializing. Hence had to hardcode the keyspacename and others.

Application main class:

```
package com.example.cassandra;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CassandraApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CassandraApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Configuration Class:

```
package com.example.cassandra;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SchemaAction;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.CassandraConverter;
import     org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.SimpleUserTypeResolver;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.TupleTypeFactory;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:application.properties")
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration             {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Override
public String getKeyspaceName()
{
    return "bbmpanukula"; //env.getProperty("${keyspace}"); //"bbmpnukula";
}


@Bean
public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() throws     ClassNotFoundException {
    CassandraMappingContext mappingContext= new     CassandraMappingContext();
    mappingContext.setUserTypeResolver(new     SimpleUserTypeResolver(cluster().getObject(), getKeyspaceName()));
    return mappingContext;
}


@Bean
public CassandraAdminTemplate cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {

    CassandraAdminTemplate template = 
     new CassandraAdminTemplate(session().getObject(),converter());
    return template;
}


@Bean
public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() 
{
    CassandraSessionFactoryBean sess = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
    sess.setKeyspaceName(getKeyspaceName());
    sess.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
    try {
        sess.setConverter(converter());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sess.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);
    return sess;

}


@Bean
public CassandraConverter converter() throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
}


@Bean
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster()
{
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cbean =
            new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
    cbean.setPort(9042);
    cbean.setContactPoints("localhost");
    return cbean;

}

}
```

My Pom.xml is given below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>cassandra</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>cassandra</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
          <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Exception - Compilation

```
2019-02-10 16:37:04.828  INFO 24989 --- [           main]     c.e.cassandra.CassandraApplication       : Starting CassandraApplication on     LM0000841 with PID 24989 (/Users/vishnu.hari/Downloads/cassandra/target/classes started by vishnu.hari in /Users/vishnu.hari/Downloads/cassandra)
2019-02-10 16:37:04.841  INFO 24989 --- [           main]     c.e.cassandra.CassandraApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-02-10 16:37:06.241  INFO 24989 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-02-10 16:37:06.307  INFO 24989 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 51ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-02-10 16:37:06.322  INFO 24989 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-02-10 16:37:06.327  INFO 24989 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-02-10 16:37:07.222  INFO 24989 --- [           main] com.datastax.driver.core                 : DataStax Java driver 3.6.0 for Apache Cassandra
2019-02-10 16:37:07.237  INFO 24989 --- [           main] c.d.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility       : Detected Guava >= 19 in the classpath, using modern compatibility layer
2019-02-10 16:37:07.948  INFO 24989 --- [           main] com.datastax.driver.core.ClockFactory    : Using native clock to generate timestamps.
2019-02-10 16:37:08.278  INFO 24989 --- [           main] com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil       : Did not find Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, defaulting to NIO.
2019-02-10 16:37:08.412  WARN 24989 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/example/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminTemplate]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource     [com/example/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     com/codahale/metrics/Metric
2019-02-10 16:37:10.803  INFO 24989 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-10 16:37:10.826 ERROR 24989 --- [           main]     o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/example/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminTemplate]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/example/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/Metric
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at com.example.cassandra.CassandraApplication.main(CassandraApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminTemplate]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/example/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/Metric
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/example/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/Metric
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:339) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at com.example.cassandra.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c1a17b4.session(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.cassandra.CassandraConfiguration.cassandraTemplate(CassandraConfiguration.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.cassandra.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c1a17b4.CGLIB$cassandraTemplate$2(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.cassandra.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c1a17b4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a138c58c.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at com.example.cassandra.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c1a17b4.cassandraTemplate(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/Metric
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1501) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:208) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:376) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:332) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.connect(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:89) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:82) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraSessionFactoryBean.java:59) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codahale.metrics.Metric
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
... 47 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Code formatting

Comment: That's because `com/codahale/metrics/Metric` is not in classpath . I believe that's because you excluded  `<groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
          <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>` . Don't exclude that and try

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the stack trace

> nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/Metric

`cassandraTemplate` cannot be created because `com/codahale/metrics/Metric` is not available in classpath.

That class comes from the dependency `metrics-core` which you excluded

```
      <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
```

Don't exclude that dependency and try